# GWT DevMode - cannot pick up changes in the UI code on browser refresh

Tags: java, maven, gwt, intellij-idea

I have a GWT app which does not pickup changes on the UI code, even I refresh the browser (no error, the app works fine). The app is run through `$mvn gwt:run` Could it be that the `outputdirectory` in the maven POM is not properly set?:

> [WARNING] Your POM  does not match your hosted
>   webapp WEB-INF/classes folder for GWT Hosted browser to see your
>   classes.

Comment: Try doing a **Project > Clean...** and a Build? This should clear out the `WEB-INF/classes` folder and re-copy the resources from `src` to `classes`.

Comment: @Churro That sound manual to me,

Comment: does this happen all the time? I assumed this happened once. Do you have **Project > Build Automatically** selected?

Comment: @Churro I'm using IntelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this warning too, but it's ok for me because I want to use maven's default target directory for my builds... (so there are no build-artifacts under /src/main/webapp). The gwt-eclipse plugin picks the output-dir path on launch so I've never had such problems...

Can you ensure your build puts all files unter /target/ ?

Additionally are you sure, that it's not a browser caching issue?